# How to load a percentage of data from huggingface load_dataset

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to download the "librispeech_asr" dataset which totals 29GB, but due to limited space in google colab, I'm not able to download/load the dataset i.e. the notebook crashes.

So I did some research and found the `split` argument that we can pass in the `load_dataset` function to download a part of dataset, but it is still downloading the whole 30GB dataset on notebook. The argument `split` is not working...

```
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("librispeech_asr", 'clean', split=['train.360[:50%]', 'validation'])
```

I was trying to load only 50% of 'train.360' data but I'm unable to do so.

What is the correct method and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to report that on their official forum?

Answer (score 2):

You can use their String API or ReadInstruction API explained [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#slice-splits)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Comment: The documentation that is linked is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

You can build train, test, validate splits with different sizes (e.g. split='train[:10%]'); However, the whole data (file) will loaded into the dataset object