# Is there any way to download only a partition of the whole dataset from huggingface

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to finetune a facebook/wav2vec2 model on Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) with [common voice dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/mozilla-foundation/common_voice_16_0), but I stumbled upon an issue that my disk space is not enough to hold this large 256GB dataset.

Then I tried dataset splitting and slicing from `datasets.load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_16_0", "en", split="train[:20%]")`, but, instead of loading 20 percent of the dataset, the whole dataset was loaded anyway.

I found [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75932871/11537191), where Mohammad replied that the whole dataset will be loaded regardless of slicing argument, but his answered wasn't confirmed, so I just want to ask if it is really the case that we cannot load only a part of dataset?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datasets` works by downloading the dataset completely and returning the requested data.

To download partial data you can consider streaming instead:

```
from datasets import 

num_samples_to_take = 100
dataset_name = "mozilla-foundation/common_voice_16_0"
ds = load_dataset(dataset_name, "en", split="train", streaming=True)
ds = ds.take(num_samples_to_take)
```